# Why is Google not showing links to my site for a link: search?

Tags: google

`link:article-stack.com` is giving 5 links. all are from my site only.

I wrote an article over sulekha.com many days. But it doesnt come in result until i secially search for it.

Previously `link:article-stack.com` search  was showing 6 links. some of them were from wordpress as well. Now those links are not coming in result while all links are still present.

Comment: Please comment for negative voting. It'll help me to improve question contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my observation, i found that google itself is not good for backlink search. Google direct search result and webmaster tools result contradict each other. As per @Simone Carletti suggestion i tried www.majesticseo.com which giving more accuracy than other any other tool or search.
Thanks for all of your support

Answer (score 3):

Site: queries via. Google are not very accurate for reporting inbound links. The [same query via. Yahoo site explorer](http://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com/search?p=http://article-stack.com) shows over 2,000 links to your domain (although many of them are suspicious looking, which is probably not helping your case).

As DisgruntledGoat suggested, get onto Webmaster Tools which will give you better numbers, and give it some time.

Comment: I had gone through but i found it is also being updated manually. just see my other question http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3404/google-webmaster-tool-is-not-updating-my-site-related-information. suggest me if any manual updation require

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible reasons the most likely being that the link to your site is from a newly-indexed page. If it's only been a few days and neither website is really popular then Google has not spidered the link yet.

It may take a few weeks for Googlebot to even find the link, then maybe more days or weeks for it to list it in its index for `link:` queries.

Other possible reasons:

- Google doesn't show all links to your site, only a portion.
- The links to your site could use `rel="nofollow"` and won't be counted.
- The links use Javascript or Flash some other method that the search engines don't recognise.

Your best bet is to sign up to [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/). Once your site is verified there you will get a much better picture of links to your site and other goodies. Another useful tool is [Open Site Explorer](http://www.opensiteexplorer.org) but often it will be behind Google etc.

Comment: I had checked for rel="nofollow". So there is no issue. My domain and site is 4-5 month old. I suppose its enough time for Googlebot. google shown links first time after 5 days of opening. After that they had decreased the links instead of increasing.

Comment: @articlestack Have you checked the sulekha.com page in Google? It may not be indexed yet or have the most up-to-date version.

Comment: ya i had checked it. and it is coming properly

Answer (score 0):

you're sure that the other links aren't `rel="nofollow"` ? Otherwise search engines won't consider them in SEO rankings.

edit:
Misunderstood your question slightly. If you're talking about your own links to internal pages then it just means Google isn't indexing them quickly. This can be improved significantly by using the WordPress sitemaps addon: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/ (I'm assuming you're using WordPress). It helps Google index every page on your website by listing all of them. I highly recommend it.

Comment: ya im sure, even u can be after visiting any link on my site

Comment: updated answer...

Comment: i dint get you.