# Google webmaster tool is not updating my site related information

Tags: google-search-console

I am very thanks ful to google webbmaster since it suggested me many of the pages which were causing 404.

But i am surprised why were this information still being shown even after one week of repairing the page links.

Comment: I am also having the same situation. It takes a long time for the back links to get updated. It would be really appreciable is there is any mention of when the record was last updated. But the system is quite sensitive in updating the errors if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the report in Google Webmaster Tools is necessarily updated that often. There should be a date when the report was last updated below the table of crawl errors on the right hand side. How often it is updated *might* depend on how much traffic your site gets?

For instance, for a site I'm currently looking at (today being Sept 30, 2010), the report was last updated on Sep 7, 2010 - over 3 weeks ago!

Also, the right hand column of that report should indicate when the fault was detected. If this was *before* you corrected the problem then it probably isn't a problem any more!

Comment: ya google webmaster tools is updating. But he is little bit lazzy;-)