# problem with google search in link:article-stack.com

Tags: google, google-search-console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why google is not showing links to my site in result?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3320/why-google-is-not-showing-links-to-my-site-in-result)

If I google `link:article-stack.com`, it shows 4 interlinks in result.

1. If it shows interlinks it should show > 250 links. But it is showing 4 only.
2. Google webmaster is saying 8 external links. But google search is not showing it
3. Previously it was showing 6 links

   a) 1 from stackoverflow
   b) 1 from wordpress
   c) 4 from my own site

then it came to 5. Now it is 4 only. While there are

```
a) 3-4 links on stackoverflow
b) 3-4 links on stackexchange
c) 3 links on wordpress
d) 4-5 links on sulekha
```

I already had checked that all external pages, which are pointing to my site, are indexed and cached by google.

Am i searching in wrong way?

Comment: See the answers for this question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3320/why-google-is-not-showing-links-to-my-site-in-result/3328 that you asked two weeks ago about exactly the same thing.

Comment: thanks @Tim, but there are 3 questions which looks very much similar but having different sense. Question u marked wr related to link search only. this Qt is related to comparison b/w direct google search and google webmaster result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my observation, I found that Google itself is not good for backlink search. Google direct search result and webmaster tools result contradict each other. As per @Simone Carletti suggestion, I tried www.majesticseo.com which giving more accuracy than other any other tool or search.

As per my knowledge, there is no option to close a question for any further comments and answers. Please suggest me if any.